# Properties of bijections

Tags: combinatorics, functions, equivalence-relations

If a bijection exists between set A={a1, a2, ...} and set B={b1, b2, ...} such that **a1** maps to **b1** and **a2** maps to **b2**, etc., does this mean if we find a relationship **R** between **a1** and **b1** (i.e. **f(b1)** is always twice the size of **f(a1)**), then that relationship must also be true for **a2** and **b2**?

Comment: Please say more on what you me by a relationship between $a_1$ and $b_1$ what is $f$ is this context?

Also what does $X = Y$ mean? Are they sets? If so do you mean $|X| = |Y|$.

Comment: A relationship could be any pattern that connects element a1 to element b1 such as equality, etc. 
"f" could be any arbitrary function that's used to identify a relation between a1 and b1, not just what I have in my example. *Deleted P.S.* ignore that

Answer (score 2):

The word you're looking for is *compatibility* ...

For a function $f$ and a relation $R$, we say that *f respects R*, or *is compatible* with it, iff 
$$\forall x,y :: x \ R \ y \implies (f \ x) \ R \ (f \ y)$$
ie *related items have related images* :)

Now if we have a bijection $f : A \cong B$ that is *also* compatible with a relation $R$, then we obtain the property you desire 
(... or not ...it's late where I am...)

Anyhow, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

No. Your $f$ could be $f(a_i) = i a_i$ if your sets are right. Your $f$ can be taken to set up a correspondence, like pairing up people with seats in a cinema. Many pairings are possible (just shuffle the people around).